# How to scrape this site for topics that I answer in

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

### Question

How can I modify my script to successfully show me the number of answers that I have made by topics.

### Code

This was a script that I tried

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_topics('Juan-Gallardo'):
url = "http://www.quora.com/" + 'Juan-Gallardo' + "/topics"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
bod = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 40
while no_of_pagedowns:
bod.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
time.sleep(0.3)
no_of_pagedowns-=1

topics = [t.text.encode('ascii', 'replace') for t in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("name_text")]
counts = [c.text.encode('ascii', 'replace').split(' ')[0] for c in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("name_meta")]

li = [[topics[i], int(counts[i])] for i in xrange(len(topics)) if counts[i] != '']

browser.quit()

return li
```

### Errors

[image]

Comment: Has the answer helped? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an argument for the `get_topics()` function:

```
def get_topics(user):
    url = "http://www.quora.com/" + user + "/topics"
    ...
```

Then, call the function this way:

```
get_topics('Juan-Gallardo')
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure what I did wrong here though https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/d0f82c7ab809ada8fedd